# SparkSQL/DataFrames does not work in spark-shell and application

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, apache-spark-sql

It does not work when I tried to follow the example from [HBase Guide](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes)
. It occurs the following errors:`java.lang.NullPointerException`, the whole info is as follows. I guess a object is null , then call the method by the object of null , but I don't know which objec is null . who can help me , thanks a lot.

---

*Thanks to everybody,  the problem is resolved now, I debugged this code in a application with Intellij IDE, I found that the HBaseContext was not instantiated, so It works well  when I created a HBaseContext object. just like this: `val hbaseContext = new HBaseContext(sc, config, null)`*

reference:https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_basic_spark

" *At the root of all Spark and HBase integration is the HBaseContext. The HBaseContext takes in HBase configurations and pushes them to the Spark executors. This allows us to have an HBase Connection per Spark Executor in a static location.* "

---

```
hadoop@master:~$ spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-shell --jars /home/yang/Downloads/hbase-spark-2.0.0-20160316.173537-2.jar 
...
SQL context available as sqlContext.
scala> def catalog = s"""{
     |        |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table1"},
     |        |"rowkey":"key",
     |        |"columns":{
     |          |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
     |          |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"string"}
     |        |}
     |      |}""".stripMargin
catalog: String

scala> case class HBaseRecord(
     |    col0: String,
     |    col1: String)
defined class HBaseRecord

scala> val data = (0 to 255).map { i =>  HBaseRecord(i.toString, "extra")}
data: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[HBaseRecord] = Vector(HBaseRecord(0,extra), HBaseRecord(1,extra), HBaseRecord(2,extra), HBaseRecord(3,extra), HBaseRecord(4,extra), HBaseRecord(5,extra), HBaseRecord(6,extra), HBaseRecord(7,extra), HBaseRecord(8,extra), HBaseRecord(9,extra), HBaseRecord(10,extra), HBaseRecord(11,extra), HBaseRecord(12,extra), HBaseRecord(13,extra), HBaseRecord(14,extra), HBaseRecord(15,extra), HBaseRecord(16,extra), HBaseRecord(17,extra), HBaseRecord(18,extra), HBaseRecord(19,extra), HBaseRecord(20,extra), HBaseRecord(21,extra), HBaseRecord(22,extra), HBaseRecord(23,extra), HBaseRecord(24,extra), HBaseRecord(25,extra), HBaseRecord(26,extra), HBaseRecord(27,extra), HBaseRecord(28,extra), HBaseRecord(29,extra), HBaseRecord(30,extra), HBaseRecord(31,extra), HBase...
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase
import org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase

scala> sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5")).format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").save()
<console>:35: error: not found: value HBaseTableCatalog
              sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5")).format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").save()
                                                          ^ 

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase.{HBaseTableCatalog}
import org.apache.spark.sql.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableCatalog

scala> sc.parallelize(data).toDF.write.options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5")).format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").save()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.<init>(DefaultSource.scala:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at <init>(<console>:55)
    at .<init>(<console>:59)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


scala>
```

by the way,the following is the information of my environment:

- Spark: version 1.6.0
- Scala: version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91)
- Hbase: Version 1.2.2
- Hadoop: Version 2.4.0

Comment: add Hbase client jar as dependency and try.

Comment: I have been added all the jars from the "hbase/lib" folder. But the error still occurs.